# NSNumberFormatter format currency not working

Tags: ios, string, swift, swift2

I have a number formatter:

```
let currencyFormatter:NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        currencyFormatter.currencyCode = "$"
```

Set it for label:

```
cell.ValueLabel.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(product.price)
```

And get `100.00` instead of `100.00$`

Comment: Why would you hardcode the currency symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set currencySymbol instead of currencyCode

```
let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
currencyFormatter.currencySymbol = "$"
currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(100)  // $100.00"
```

else

```
let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
currencyFormatter.currencyCode = "USD"
currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(100)  // $100.00"
```